# Is there a name for making things that shouldn't be done difficult to do and things that should be done easy to do in an architecture?

Tags: design-patterns

I used to think this was called Design by Contract but I realize that Design by Contract is actually referring to using frameworks to do validations (or something similar). But I'm assuming there is a term for the idea of creating an architecture using techniques that make it easy to do the right things and hard to do the wrong things.

Answer (score 0):

Defensive Programming was what I was looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming